# Adding dollar amounts in PHP with smarty template system?

Tags: php, smarty

I have several dollar amounts that I need to add.  This is the code I'm currently using:

```
{php}$totalaffamount = $pendingcommissions + $balance + $withdrawn;
echo $totalaffamount;{/php}
```

Here are the values of each:

```
$pendingcommissions = $5.00 USD
$balance = $1000.00 USD
$withdrawn = $393.99 USD
```

I want to display the total like this:

```
$1398.99
```

However I keep getting `0` as the output which I'm guessing is because of the dollar sign and USD that are in the variables...  Does anyone know what I need to change my code to for this to work?

Comment: move dollar sign off the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use values only for this, using $ signs is not the correct way for adding things up

```
$pendingcommissions = 5.00;
$balance = 1000.00;
$withdrawn = 393.99;

$total = $pendingcommissions + $balance + $withdrawn;

echo '$'.$total;
```

:)